# refine search values are not displayed in the opencart theme

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, opencart

I'm using opencart cms to manage my online shop. Recently I decided to add some filters to refine the search of my products. I did everything according to this tutorial: [link to tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-filters-in-opencart--cms-22594)

So I have added two filters: size and color. To each of the filters I added three options: red, white, black and S, M, L.

Everything seems to be working except one. In the front end of the site I can only see the name of the filters: "size", "color" and the button "refine search". However I cannot see the selections. This is the image what I see in the frontend: [link to the screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/7nr0p9fov/)

However if I look at the source code of the site, I see that server returns the options. This is how the code looks like:

```
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Refine Search</div>
      <div class="list-group">
        <a class="list-group-item">Size</a>
        <div class="list-group-item">
          <div id="filter-group7">
                        <label class="checkbox">
          <input name="filter[]" type="checkbox" value="24" />
          L (1)</label>
                                <label class="checkbox">
          <input name="filter[]" type="checkbox" value="23" />
          M (0)</label>
                                <label class="checkbox">
          <input name="filter[]" type="checkbox" value="22" />
          S (0)</label>
                      </div>
    </div>
        <a class="list-group-item">Color</a>
    <div class="list-group-item">
      <div id="filter-group6">
                        <label class="checkbox">
          <input name="filter[]" type="checkbox" value="21" />
          White (3)</label>
                                <label class="checkbox">
          <input name="filter[]" type="checkbox" value="20" />
          Black (3)</label>
                                <label class="checkbox">
          <input name="filter[]" type="checkbox" value="19" />
          Red (2)</label>
                      </div>
    </div>
      </div>
```

Maybe someone will know where is the problem? I use a standart Induca theme, but I dont think that its the reason of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and I found answer!
You should go to layouts options, find there "category" template and add (+) there "filter" to left column panel.

Description there: http://www.pavothemes.com/blog/tutorials/137-how-to-use-opencart-filter.html